# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, array, funciones

Buenas tardes llevo trabajando con una consulta tipo insert en mysql-php para que el insert sea valido para cada tipo de tablas independientemente de sus columnas este es el error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php(21): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/html/TEST/insertController.php(4): Insert->load() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php on line 21

y este es el código:

```
<?php
    class Insert{
        private $connect;
        public function __construct(){
            require_once("connect.php");
            $this->connect=Connect::connection();
        }

        public function load(){
            $sql="";$sql2="";$rute="";
            $columns=$this->connect->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM TEST WHERE Field NOT IN('ID')");
            $columns->execute(array());
            while($row=$columns->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $sql=$sql . $row["Field"] . ",";
                    $sql2=$sql2 . ":" . $row["Field"] . ",";
                    $rute=$rute . '":' . $row["Field"] . '"=>$_POST["' . $row["Field"] . '"],';
            }
            $ins=$this->connect->prepare($sql=str_replace(",)",")","INSERT INTO TEST(" . $sql . ") VALUES(" . $sql2 . ")"));
            $rute=str_replace("],.","]",$rute . ".");
            $rute=$rute;
            $ins->execute(array($rute));
        }
    }
?>
```

El constructor simplemente realiza la conexión a la base de datos, y la función en el ciclo while crea la consulta para la tabla test:

INSERT INTO TEST(NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES(:NOMBRE,:APELLIDO,:EDAD)

El array que se crea en el while ($rute) y que paso en como parámetro en execute es este:

":NOMBRE"=>$_POST["NOMBRE"],":APELLIDO"=>$_POST["APELLIDO"],":EDAD"=>$_POST["EDAD"]

El problema es que me genera este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php(21): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/html/TEST/insertController.php(4): Insert->load() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/TEST/insertModel.php on line 21

Pero como se puede ver en el array estoy pasando las 3 columnas que afecto en la consulta.
Ya converti el string en array con explode y con array pero el problema persiste,

La idea es no tener que contruir ninguna consulta si no que la funcion lo haga y la ejecute en base a la tabla.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda y les deseo un buen dia.

PD: El formulario que envia los datos tambien tiene los mismos 3 campos.

Comment: Los marcadores de `:NOMBRE` tienen que ser puestos entre comillas simples en la consulta, algo así: **`INSERT INTO TEST(NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES(':NOMBRE',':APELLIDO',':EDAD')`** Supongo que lo podrás lograr modificando esta parte: `$sql2=$sql2 . "':" . $row["Field"] . "',";`

Comment: te agradezco mucho tu aporte pero al enviar los datos desde el formulario ingresa en la base de datos esto:                                                                            
| ID | NOMBRE    | APELLIDO  | EDAD  |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | ERNESTO   | LURA      | 25    |
|  2 | FELIPE    | MARIN     | 45    |
|  3 | Sebastian | Lopez     | 12    |
|  4 | Loren | YA     | 12    |
|  5 | :NOMBRE   | :APELLIDO | :EDAD |
|  6 | :NOMBRE   | :APELLIDO | :EDAD |

Comment: es decir agrega :EDAD :APELLIDO :NOMBRE no el valor del input

Comment: No sé, tu código es algo confuso. Por ejemplo, en `$rute` (que son los datos que pareces pasar para inserción), metes valores de `$row["Field"]` .

Comment: lo hago porque los nombres de los imputs son iguales a las columnas y al hacer la insersion quede esta array:":NOMBRE"=>$_POST["NOMBRE"],":APELLIDO"=>$_POST["APELLIDO"],":EDAD"=>$_POST["EDAD"]

Comment: disculpame es que soy algo nuevo en este tema.

Comment: Ya, pero `$_POST` es un array como cualquier otro. Entonces puedes optimizar el código: 1º. Eliminando la consulta `SHOW COLUMNS`; 2º. Usando la misma info que tienes en `$_POST` para armar la consulta. En este caso los nombres de llave del array que es `$_POST` serían las columnas y los valores de cada dato serían los valores a insertar, pasándolos en el `execute`. Así el código queda más claro y queda optimizado.

Answer (score 0):

Como solucion temporal pase la data de los imputs directamente a la query ejemplo:
INSERT INTO TEST(NOMBRE) VALUES('MARIA') en lugar de pasarlo en el execute como array